# Как восстановить базу данных на Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: база-данных, ubuntu, postgresql

Всем здравствуйте, есть сервер Ubuntu 20.04 на котором я установил PostgreSQL при помощи следующей инструкции:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных работает, вопросов нет. Вопросы начали появляться когда я попытался восстановить резервную копию базы данных которая есть у меня на Windows. В основном я пытался использовать два метода

1. psql -U myuser -d mydb-a -f /root/gdl333/backup.sql -h localhost - Не работает. Либо permissions denied, либо когда я использую sudo в начале, пишет Sorry, try again неверный(хотя пароль правильный)
2. pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -f db_backup.sql - После того как нажал Enter - тишина... более часа ждал, ничего не произошло

Помогите пожалуйста уже как-то это решить, потому что уже подгорает

Comment: Пункт 1 вынуждает меня задать вопрос — а вы вообще знаете что такое sudo и как он работает?

Comment: В общем-то п.2 требует ввода пароля. Не знаю как в Linux, в Windows можно установить SET PGPASSWORD = xxxxxxxx и тогда запрашивать не будет при восстановлении. Наверняка у Вас можно сделать также, хотя это и не безопасно. А Ваша команда, как я понял целых "более часа" ждала пока вы введёте пароль.

Answer (score 0):

Начну с конца: pg_restore не может использоваться с plain-text дампом и при попытке использования с sql дампом ответит

> pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.

Второй момент с вашим вызовом pg_restore - он действительно абсолютно ничего не делает, а ждёт собственно содержимое дампа. Потому что `-f db_backup.sql`, как однозначно описывает [документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) (выделение жирным моё), совсем не имя файла дампа:

> Specify **output** file for generated script

Эта опция позволяет pg_restore взять файл дампа custom или directory формата и транслировать в plain text файл SQL команд. Соответственно,

```
pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -f db_backup.sql
```

после запуска не использует `-h` и `-U`, готова *писать в* db_backup.sql и ждёт данные в `stdin`, т.к. не был указан файл или директория для чтения. Это допустимая форма вызова, например, читать результат pg_dump через unix pipe от архиватора или как результат какой-нибудь другой команды.

---

grant all privileges on database делает строго то что написано, а не что может подразумевать пользователь. На уровне on database есть всего 3 привилегии: на собственно подключение к этой базе, на использование временных таблиц, на создание новых схем. Только эти привилегии и предоставляются.

`pg_dump` предполагает дальнейшую работу с дампом от `superuser`. Возможно работать от непривилегированного пользователя, но сопутствующие возможные приключения и меры по их предотвращению - ответственность оператора.

Обычно делается

```
sudo -iu postgres
psql
# CREATE USER "$NEWOWNER" PASSWORD '$NEWPASS';
# CREATE DATABASE ${NEWDB} OWNER "$NEWOWNER";
# REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE $NEWDB FROM public;
psql -d ${NEWDB} -f dump.sql
```

если старое имя пользователя и нового совпадают. Если имена пользователей разные, то стоит снять дамп с исходной базы повторно с ключами `--no-acl --no-owner` и на целевой базе сделать

```
sudo -iu postgres
psql
# CREATE USER "$NEWOWNER" PASSWORD '$NEWPASS';
# CREATE DATABASE ${NEWDB} OWNER "$NEWOWNER";
# REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE $NEWDB FROM public;
psql -d ${NEWDB}
# перенести вручную все необходимые CREATE EXTENSION
psql -d ${NEWDB} -f dump.sql -U $NEWOWNER # может быть ещё некоторые параметры подключения, в зависимости от правил в pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: Не совсем понял содержимое вашего ответа. Так как совсем недавно начал работать с PostgreSQL. Возможно есть какая-то статья или что-то подобное, которая может мне прояснить всё